# Django entry creating. Method in views/other file or as a method of model class

Tags: django, view, models

Django creating entry.

1) As seen in Django docs:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignField(User)
    title = models.CharField(#some_params)
    content = models.CharField(#some_params)
    date = models.DateTimeField(#some_params)
```

Then in my views I can:

```
new_article = Article(user=user, title="abc", content="xyz", date = datetime.utcnow())
new_article.save()
```

2) But it also can be done like by calling method within Article class, ie:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignField(User)
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.CharField()

    def add_article(self, title, content):  
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.save()
```

and then in views:

```
title = "abc"
content = "xyz"
new_article = Article(user=user)
new_article.add_article(abc, xyz)
```

I am asking because I have seen both ways of adding content into database. I would like to ask:

1. What is better practice?
2. Any concerns about security in 2nd example?

Comment: What do you mean by security concerns? To my eyes the first way is cleaner just because the time you read it you know the record is saved. I don't see a big difference though (except that no abc and xyz variables exist in your last snippet :P).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is, in my opinion, better practice. `add_article` is unnecessary, because you can set the date by using the `auto_now` property of the date field, and everything else is already built-in. You'll have less code and less maintenance.

Comment: I'd also go for option 1. Adding methods like `add_article` to the model itself feels wrong. At least because it's a unintuitiv API. Adding an article to an article? Doesn't sound right, does it?